# Sometimes my icons in my list view are not showing

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-imageview, custom-adapter

My problem is that I have implemented a custom arrayadapter, that fetches images from an url and sets them to an imageview. It works, sort of. Sometimes some of the images are not showing up. Somtimes it's only one image, somtimes it's three and in no apparent order. Only thing that's reasonably consistent is that it seems to be image number 3 in my arraylist.

My custom adapter:

```
public CustomAdapter( Context context, int textViewResourceId, List items )
{
        super( context, textViewResourceId, items );
        this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
{
    View v = convertView;
    if ( v == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater vi =  ( LayoutInflater ) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        v = vi.inflate( R.layout.list_item, parent, false );
    }
    Object o = items.get( position );
    if  ( o != null )
    {
            TextView textView = ( TextView ) v.findViewById( R.id.listItem );
            ImageView imageView = ( ImageView ) v.findViewById( R.id.icon );

            if ( textView != null )
            {
                textView.setText( o.toString() );
            }
            if ( imageView != null )
            {
                if ( o instanceof XmlGuide )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap( downloadIcon( ( ( XmlGuide ) o ).getIcon() ) );
                    }
                    catch( Exception e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return v;
}

private Bitmap downloadIcon( String uri ) throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL( uri );
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( stream );
    stream.close();
    return icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. The problem is that Android < 2.3 is not handling jpg images very well. There is one fix, which will fix this in most cases, but not all.

You can read more about it here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

Answer (score 0):

having a blocking network part during your getView is not recommanded.

use

```
setImageUri(Uri.parse(o.getIcon());
```

is certainly better.

Comment: My getIcon() returns a string, which does not really work so well with setImageUri

Comment: which is why I wrote "Uri.parse(o.getIcon())"